# Reflection To Execute Class With Generic Type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to dynamically execute a method on a class that uses a generic type, after finding it using reflection (which looks for an interface implementation).

An example of where I am stuck is below. Help is much appreciated.

**Setup**

```
public interface IActionRequired<T> where T : class {
    void DoThis(T[] receivedObjects);
}

public class BookDetails {
    public int BookId { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }
}

public class LibraryBookReturned : IActionRequired<BookDetails>
{
    public void DoThis(BookDetails[] receivedObjects)
    {
        foreach(var book in receivedObjects)
            System.Console.WriteLine(book.BookName);
    }
}
```

**Example Attempt Using Reflection**

Below, I am just using the first implementation but in the real world I'll be using a naming convention to locate the correct implementation.

```
        var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        var listOfImplementations = 
                GetAllTypesImplementingOpenGenericType(typeof(IActionRequired<>), assembly);
        var implementation = listOfImplementations.FirstOrDefault();
        var implementationUsesInterface = implementation.GetInterfaces() [0];
        var interfaceUsesType = implementationUsesInterface.GetGenericArguments() [0];
```

I understand that the below will not work (I get an error saying interfaceUsesType is a variable not a type) but it indicates what I would like to do:

```
        var instance = 
            assembly.CreateInstance(implementation.FullName) as IActionRequired<interfaceUsesType>;
        var results = this.CheckForMessages<interfaceUsesType>();
        instance.DoThis(results);
```

Comment: Think you might be looking for something like this: [How To: Call a generic method with a runtime type](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/how-to-call-a-generic-method-with-a-runtime-type/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@rickvbosch 's answer was (very nearly) what I needed and definitely the right way to go. However, since I was trying to do two things effectively, I've upvoted his answer and added what I did to get things working as the accepted answer to my original problem, using his suggestion.

```
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(implementation);
        var results = this.GetType()
            .GetMethod("CheckForMessages", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .MakeGenericMethod(interfaceUsesType)
            .Invoke(this, null) as object[];

        if(results.Count() > 0)
            instance.GetType()
            .GetMethod("DoThis")
            .Invoke(instance, new object[] {results});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to emit a run-time type specific version of the generic method. Have a look at the [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod) for that one.

> The MakeGenericMethod method allows you to write code that assigns specific types to the type parameters of a generic method definition, thus creating a MethodInfo object that represents a particular constructed method. If the ContainsGenericParameters property of this MethodInfo object returns true, you can use it to invoke the method or to create a delegate to invoke the method.

In short (pseudo) code:

```
this.GetType()
    .GetMethod("CheckForMessages")
    .MakeGenericMethod(interfaceUsesType)
    .Invoke(this, null);
```

You can also read up on it here: [How To: Call a generic method with a runtime type](https://www.rickvandenbosch.net/blog/how-to-call-a-generic-method-with-a-runtime-type/)